# Why is Outlook 2010 opening file hyperlinks in Internet Explorer?

Tags: excel, internet-explorer, hyperlink, outlook, file-type

I have several emails sent to me each day which all contain a hyperlink to a local file in a directory.
I would simply like it to open the link in excel but instead it opens Internet Explorer and then says 'Internet Explorer cannot display webpage'
Is there a way I can change it so it opens in Excel and not IE?
Many thanks,
Mw

Comment: What's the url? if it's showing up as `http://`, then IE is being properly invoked, because that's a web address. You probably want a `file://` url, which would invoke Explorer, not IE.

Comment: The code that builds the email link is: <a href=file://...

Answer (score 1):

check that Excel is the default program for the file extension. Alternatively you could edit the hyperlink to start with "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\excel.exe" with the file path following. (make sure that you edit the path for your version of Excel.